# How to implement search on a specific website inside an app?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an app in which we can scan the barcode and it displays information about the food item. So, I found that for SuperStore (Canada) we can just type in the barcode number in the search bar(on their website) and it displays the result. I want my app to take the barcode number and search for item. How can I do this inside my app?

Comment: If there is no API offered, then you should find the url and parameters of the search request and do the same thing in your app. But I don't think it is a legal way.

Comment: @JsW The thing is that I am doing this for a school project and it might become an issue there.

Comment: Try google [Chrome's developer tools] (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), it can reveal details of the network request where you can find all the thing you need like request header.